# Setting errorPage in Umbraco

Tags: .net, umbraco, http-error

I am developing a web application using Umbraco. I create a content called PageNotFound and, in the errors section of umbracoSettings.config file, I put the node id of that for 404 error404. The problem is that, with IIS 7, IIS always looks for the HttpErrors section in web.config and does not pay attention to umbracoSettings.config.

What should I do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your web.config (system.webServer section) you can tell the site to pass all of the error handling through to the application:

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```

This has the disadvantage that Umbraco doesn't handle anything but .aspx pages that are not found.

You could make it better by doing something like this instead:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
       <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
       <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/non-existing-page.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

The non-existing-page.aspx does not exist yet in Umbraco, so it triggers a 404 (because it has the aspx extension) and.. presto: Umbraco handles the 404 perfectly!

Comment: Thank you. But the actual problem is that I did your second suggestion, but in my "page not found" page that I defined, I load some bloks using XSLT which when I directly browse that page they appear but when the page shows when I input invalid URL, those block does not appear!

Comment: I don't know why that is, seems like the logic in your XSLT might be wrong then. Do they appear if you go directly to yoursite.com/non-existing-page.aspx?

Comment: When I change the errorMode to Detailed those blocks appear! It is Weird!

Comment: But I do not want Detailed since destroy all my redirect strategies!

Comment: No! For me also is really strange! With Custom is does NOT work! only with Detailed the XSLT content is loaded! I think the problem is because of some setting in IIS 7.

Comment: Try to do the redirect to non-existingpage.aspx?umbDebugShowTrace=true to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Alright, not sure why this happens, please create a new question and put the error details in there and what the non-working macros are supposed to do, so I (we) can have a look!

Comment: Would be good if you could mark this answer as a correct answer as well, thanks!

Comment: Using 4.7.1, this method works for nonexistingpage.aspx as well as /nonexistingpage (no suffix) XSLTs render, all is good. Thanks!

Comment: This URL doesnt display the configured Umbraco 404 page: /a/valid/path.aspx/followed-by-something-invalid/. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

The 500 errors did not work until I added

```
existingResponse="Replace"
```

like that

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/non-existing-page.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <error statusCode="500" path="error.html" responseMode="File" />
</httpErrors>
```

Comment: Just a small gotcha, the path attribute for the 500 error is a physical path. so if you had the error.html file inside a views folder you would use path="views\error.html" (note the backslash).