# add custom 404 pages in umbraco 4.7

Tags: error-handling, umbraco

I'm trying to add custom 404 pages into umbraco
even though I got them working in several projects, in this umbraco 4.7 it does not work.

so, what do I have,
multi site each with a few languages.

my umbracoSettings contains this:

```
    <errors>
      <error404>
        <errorPage culture="default">1842</errorPage>
        <errorPage culture="en-GB">1842</errorPage>
        <errorPage culture="nl-BE">1843</errorPage>
        <errorPage culture="fr-BE">1844</errorPage>
      </error404>
    </errors>
```

just as it is in other projects
though i keep getting the IIS 404 page.

so, i tried the solution in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471683/setting-errorpage-in-umbraco)
both the passThrough and the custom solution don't seem to work

the passThrough gives this:

> Page not found No umbraco document matches the url
>   'http://www.mysite.be/en/facebook'
>
> umbraco tried this to match it using this xpath
>   query'/domainprefixes-are-used-so-i-do-not-work')
>
> This page can be replaced with a custom 404 page by adding the id of
>   the umbraco document to show as 404 page in the
>   /config/umbracoSettings.config file. Just add the id to the
>   '/settings/content/errors/error404' element.
>
> For more information, visit information about custom 404 on the
>   umbraco website.

and custom gives this result:

> Page not found No umbraco document matches the url
>   'http://solex.d01-win-dev.be/non-existing-page.aspx?404;http://solex.d01-win-dev.be:80/en/facebook'
>
> umbraco tried this to match it using this xpath
>   query'/domainprefixes-are-used-so-i-do-not-work')
>
> This page can be replaced with a custom 404 page by adding the id of
>   the umbraco document to show as 404 page in the
>   /config/umbracoSettings.config file. Just add the id to the
>   '/settings/content/errors/error404' element.
>
> For more information, visit information about custom 404 on the umbraco website.

it looks to me as if he does not go towards the umbracoSettings to fetch my error404 mappings.
did something change in 4.7 that you need to activate custom error pages trough a web.config key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for those people interested, or who might ever have the same issues
it was solved without any of those web.config changes.

but by using a custom 404 handler we added to the `404handlers.config`
like this

```
  <notFound assembly="ProjectLibrary" type="Custom404"/>
```

and still adding the error pages in the `umbracoSettings.config`
like this

```
  <errors>
      <error404>
        <errorPage culture="default">1842</errorPage>
        <errorPage culture="en-GB">1842</errorPage>
        <errorPage culture="nl-BE">1843</errorPage>
        <errorPage culture="fr-BE">1844</errorPage>
      </error404>
    </errors>
```

the custom handler looks like this:

```
    public class Custom404 : INotFoundHandler
    {
        #region INotFoundHandler Members

        private int _redirectID = -1;

        public bool CacheUrl
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public bool Execute(string url)
        {
            //Variable for keeping track whether the handling of the request was successful
            bool _success = false;
            XmlNode error404Node = umbraco.UmbracoSettings.GetKeyAsNode("/settings/content/errors/error404");

            // _redirectID =;
            XmlNode cultureErrorNode;
            try
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Trace.Write("test", HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"] + "/" + url);
                string sDomein = findDomein(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"] + "/" + url);
                HttpContext.Current.Trace.Write("test", sDomein);
                if (Domain.Exists(sDomein))
                {
                    Domain d = Domain.GetDomain(sDomein);
                    // test if a 404 page exists with current culture
                    HttpContext.Current.Trace.Write("test", d.Language.CultureAlias);
                    cultureErrorNode = error404Node.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("errorPage [@culture = '{0}']", d.Language.CultureAlias));
                    if (cultureErrorNode != null && cultureErrorNode.FirstChild != null)
                    {
                        _redirectID = int.Parse(cultureErrorNode.FirstChild.Value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cultureErrorNode = error404Node.SelectSingleNode("errorPage [@culture = 'default']");
                        if (cultureErrorNode != null && cultureErrorNode.FirstChild != null)
                            _redirectID = int.Parse(cultureErrorNode.FirstChild.Value);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    cultureErrorNode = error404Node.SelectSingleNode("errorPage [@culture = 'default']");
                    if (cultureErrorNode != null && cultureErrorNode.FirstChild != null)
                        _redirectID = int.Parse(cultureErrorNode.FirstChild.Value);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                cultureErrorNode = error404Node.SelectSingleNode("errorPage [@culture = 'default']");
                if (cultureErrorNode != null && cultureErrorNode.FirstChild != null)
                    _redirectID = int.Parse(cultureErrorNode.FirstChild.Value);
            }
            _success = true;
            return _success;
        }


        public string findDomein(string sUrl)
        {
            if (sUrl.Contains("/"))
            {
                if (Domain.Exists(sUrl))
                {
                    return sUrl;
                }
                else
                {
                    sUrl = sUrl.Substring(0, sUrl.LastIndexOf("/"));
                    return findDomein(sUrl);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return sUrl;
            }

        }

        public int redirectID
        {
            get
            { return _redirectID; }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

hope any of you can use it whenever you find yourself in the same situation.

Comment: Thanks this worked, except in umbraco 4.7 the errorPage node is called error404 (just search & replace "errorPage" with "error404" everywhere and you're good.

Comment: By the way, this is about to be fixed in umbraco 4.7.1.1

Comment: Ps. Also need to change the GetKeysAsNode call to: .GetKeyAsNode("/settings/content/errors");

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm getting a 500 error in default.aspx (i.e. the site crashes), something about trying to set the current context twice. By the way I'm using umbraco 6 and still get this issue. Wasn't this supposed to have been fixed somewhere in the 4.x branch?