# 404s in Umbraco - only works for directories and ASPX extensions

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404, umbraco

I have an Umbraco 7 site with 404 errors configured and generally working fine as long as the URL ends in a directory name or has a .aspx file extension.

Any other URLs for files that don't exist return a 404 HTTP status but the returned page is blank. How can I configure Umbraco to return my configured 404 page for all 404 responses?

The site is currently configured with a node ID in the `error404` node in `umbracoSettings.config` and, as I say, works fine in specific cases.

I've hunted around the web but not found much help. I tried implementing my own 404 handler by implementing the `INotFoundHandler` interface but the effect was the same. I've also tried adding the following to the `system.webserver` section of `web.config` but this doesn't seem to change anything, and in any case I want the 404 page to be editable in Umbraco ideally.

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough">
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="~/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

Advice very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: finally found the answer on this very site, although it hadn't been marked as such. It's here - [Setting errorPage in Umbraco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471683/setting-errorpage-in-umbraco) - and the second part of the top-voted response from @sebastiaan was the answer. You essentially have to use web.config to trick Umbraco into handling all 404s!